# sed substitute one line into a part of the next line

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I have input like this:

```
*123456789
This is a <secret>
Other stuff here.
*987654321
This is a <secret>
Other stuff here.
```

where "Other stuff here." could be one more lines, but the number prefixed by * is variable but will always take up the whole line, and will always appear on the line immediately before the "<secret>", which is a literal, fixed string that can be matched against.

I'd like to be able to pipe this into a one-line command in a shell script such that the "*123456789" string will substitute the <secret> that appears on the next line, so that the output would be:

```
This is a *123456789
Other stuff here.
This is a *987654321
Other stuff here.
```

I'm struggling to understand multi-line processing in sed and am open to using another tool if it's cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed, you could pull in the next line using `N` and then re-arrange the parts with `s`. For example:

```
$ sed -E '/^\*[0-9]{1,}$/{N;s/(.*)\n(.*)<secret>/\2\1/}' file
This is a *123456789
Other stuff here.
This is a *987654321
Other stuff here.
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.  I had the regular expression, but didn't quite have the N syntax right.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '/^\*/ {secret=$0;next}; {gsub(/<secret>/,secret,$0); print}' input.txt 
This is a *123456789
Other stuff here.
This is a *987654321
Other stuff here.
```

If you wanted to strip the leading `*` from the "secret", you could use awk's `substr()` function:

```
$ awk '/^\*/ {secret=substr($0,2);next}; {gsub(/<secret>/,secret,$0); print}' input.txt 
This is a 123456789
Other stuff here.
This is a 987654321
Other stuff here.
```

Comment: I confirmed that this works as well. Thank you.

Comment: +1 --  maybe subjective, but `awk` 's syntax tend to be remarkably more readable than `sed` 's in this case, even if the example was simple.